# After subtracting a number from a sequence, how many of remaining numbers are positive?

Tags: c++, math, graph-algorithm

I have a number sequence of length **N**. 
I will have to do **Q** operations on this number sequence.

In each operation I will be given three integers **P, Q, V** with **P ≤ Q ≤ N** and will subtract **V** from every **iᵗʰ** integer, where **P ≤ i ≤ Q**.

After each operation, I will be given another two integers **X, Y** with **X ≤ Y ≤ N**. I will have to answer how many integers between the **Xᵗʰ** and **Yᵗʰ** (inclusive) integers are positive.

**Q** will be around **10<sup>5</sup>**. I will have to do all the operations and answer the corresponding queries in around 1/2 seconds.

What algorithm/data structure should I use? And what the procedure will be?

Note : I have a decent knowledge in Segment Trees or Binary Indexed Trees. If your solution involves these data structures, that will be great.

Comment: Author rejected my edit. So here goes the comment that this is from an ongoing contest http://www.codechef.com/SEPT13/problems/MLCHEF

Answer (score 7):

### Data structure

Use a segment tree with lazy propagation for the data structure.

In each node store:

1. Number of positive values in all child nodes
2. Smallest positive value of all child nodes (i.e. for children with values -1,3,5,-10 the smallest positive value is 3.  We ignore -1 and -10 because they are not positive. )
3. Pending value to subtract form this node (initialised to 0)

### Update

The procedure for updating a range will be:

1. Recursively descend into the segment tree until you find a node that is completely covered by the range
2. Modify the pending value for the node

### Query

The procedure for answering the query for a range will be:

1. Recursively descend into the segment tree until you find a node that is completely covered by the range
2. Recursively update the node's properties if the pending value for the node is greater than the minimum positive value

### Complexity

As each node can only become negative once, I believe this whole procedure should be O(nlogn+qlogn) where n is the length of the sequence and q is the number of operations.

### Example

Suppose we have the array [1,5,-3,4].

We will have segment nodes as follows:

```
[1,5,-3,4] min positive 1, pending change 0
[1,5] min positive 1, pending change 0
[-3,4] min positive 4, pending change 0
```

Suppose we wanted to update the whole range with a subtraction of 2, we would change this to:

```
[1,5,-3,4] min positive 1, pending change 2.
```

Now, as the pending change is >= the min positive, we need to fix the node by recursively pushing the change down into the left child and the right child.

First the left child would change to:

```
[1,5] min positive 1, pending change 2
```

We would then expand this node again and apply the updates to become

```
[-1,3] min positive 3, pending change 0
```

Next we would come to the right child which would change to

```
[-3,4] min positive 4, pending change 2
```

but no further recursion would be required as pending change < min positive.

Finally the recursion would reach the top level node again.  We use the properties of the left and right child to calculate that now the min positive is 2 (from the right child with min 4 and pending 2 giving a result of 4-2=2), and we can reset the pending change to 0 because it has been applied to the children.

Comment: I don't have any code, but I've added an example which shows how such nodes can be recursively updated.

Comment: You will only update a segment inside the query range if it contains at least one coefficient that changes from positive to non-positive.  This can only happen once per coefficient, so this limits the maximum time that can be spent in such updates to O(NlogN) over all queries.

Answer (score -3):

An easy-to-code data structure is called Segment-tree.
A faster but harder-to-code data structure is called Binary-indexed-tree.